# In Eternal Lines To Time

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> The start or end of China Sea
>   With time can show a place to be
>   To sunrise: hunger satisfied.
>   Join Olaf II, a man who died
>   Place first again and wings are mine!
>   Now hush, and I'll enjoy my wine.

Please explain these curious couplets.

HINTS:

> The title is a quote. Finish the line.
>  Although the rhyme is in couplets, the lines should be read as a whole. Or a line at a time. 
>  The first line uses cluing similar to a cryptic crossword.

Comment: The title is from Shakespeare's famous [Sonnet 18](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45087/sonnet-18-shall-i-compare-thee-to-a-summers-day) AKA "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The start of end of China Sea

> **a** - 'a' means start (as in A to Z) and is the end/s of China Sea

With time can show a place to be

> **at** - 't' for time and at is where you are

To sunrise: hunger satisfied

> **ate** - 'e' as the sun rises in the East and hunger gone

Join Olaf II, a man who died

> **late**  - 'l' is second letter of Olaf and a person passed away is late

Place first again and wings are mine!

> **alate**    - 'a' is first and alate means having winglike extensions

Now hush, and I'll enjoy my wine.

> **palate**  - 'p' is a musical term to play softly (pianissimo) and I hope you savour the wine (perhaps from neighbouring vineyards) with your palate!

The title line continues

> thou grow'st - as in the words of this rhyme.

Comment: Congratulations! I did a couple of puzzles like this some months ago but in the opposite direction. For some reason people found those easier to solve. I will indeed raise a glass Dézaley in your honor. Santé!